# awk -i inplace not working as part of a script

Tags: bash, awk

I have a file that looks like this:

```
AABBCC 10
DDEEFF 20
etc
```

I need to find a line containing let's say `AABBCC` and replace the number after it. I do it with awk:

```bash
awk -i inplace '{if($1=="AABBCC") {$2="30"} print $0}' myfile.txt
```

and it works perfectly fine

However when I do this like so inside a script

```bash
awk -i inplace '{if($1==$A) {$2=$B} print $0}' myfile.txt
```

it isn't working.

I've tried commas around $A and $B to no success. Any thoughts?
My bash is GNU bash, version 5.0.17(1)

Comment: Where are `A` and `B` defined in the second version?? `$A` says "awk find that variable named `A` and give me the value of the field with its value (`$A`)"  I don't see `A` or `B` given a value anywhere. When a variable like `A` or `B` are used undefined, `awk` simply initializes the value `0`

Comment: It's just a snippet:
#!/bin/bash
A=AABBCC
B=30
awk -i inplace '{if($1==$A) {$2=$B} print $0}' myfile.txt

Comment: That's what I'm saying `$A` `awk` variable and `$A` script variable are two different things. See how the `awk` script is run between single-quotes? Variable expansion (from a bash-script standpoint) does not occur. So your `awk` script sees `$A` and says `0`. You can either `-v A=1 -v B=3` or use the `BEGIN` rule, e.g. `awk 'BEGIN {A=1; B=3} {if($1==$A) {$ ...}' myfile.txt` Yes, you can use script variables with `-v A="$var1" -v B="$var2"`

Comment: So that would be `awk -v A="AABBCC" -v B=30 -i inplace '{if($1==$A) {$2=$B} print $0}' myfile.txt`

Comment: Shell quoting rules: Single quotes prevent parameter expansion. Therfore, `$A` is not expanded in your code, which is fortunate, because expansion would yield wrong code here anyway. You can use either the `-v` option to assign a shell variable to a awk variable (as David Rankin explained), or alternatively first  turn your shell variable into a environment variable (using `export`) and use inside awk the predefined array `ENVIRON` to access them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The below script works and gives you desired output:

```
awk -i inplace '{if($1==A) {$2=B} print $0}' A="$A" B="$B" myfile.txt
```

More about how shell variable works in awk:
https://linuxhint.com/awk_command_variables/

Hope this helps. Thanks.

Comment: FYI `'{if($1==A) {$2=B} print $0}'` = `'$1==A{$2=B}1'` in idiomatic awk.

Answer (score 1):

In your second version, e.g.

```bash
awk -i inplace '{if($1==$A) {$2=$B} print $0}' myfile.txt
```

`$A` and `$B` are `awk` variables, not shell variables. Note how the `awk` script is run between single-quotes -- shell variable expansion does not occur. So `awk` sees `$A` which it has no value for and simply initializes the variable as `0`.

In `awk`, you can either pass variable values with the `-v` option or use the `BEGIN{ ... }` rule to do it. Since you are wanting to use shell variables per-your comment, you will need to use the `-v` form, e.g.

```bash
awk -v A="AABBCC" -v B=30 -i inplace '{if($1==$A) {$2=$B} print $0}' myfile.txt
```

(**note:** using `$A` with `AABBCC` would make no sense as it wouldn't correspond to a valid field in your input, but using just `A` could. Now with `B=30`, that may correspond to the 30<sup>th</sup> field, but if you have less than 30 fields, then it would be `B` and not `$B` -- the `$` prefix in `awk` indicating the value of the variable corresponds to a specific field of input -- for which you want its value)

Now `awk` knows what `A` is and what `B` is.